# Did Dumbledore know about the existence of Delphini?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, the-cursed-child

Would he be surprised of the fact? Did he suspect something? After all, he was extraordinary intelligent and other than that, he had his spy Severus Snape amongst the Death Eater's Inner Circle.

Answer (score 6):

## We don't know

I couldn't find anything in canon that would suggest the Dumbledore knew. That doesn't mean he didn't, however.

But based on what we know of Dumbledore and Voldemort, we can gain some insight.

We learn from Cursed Child that Voldemort had Delphini with Bellatrix after the prophecy was given (I don't have the quote right now, will check when I get home). Now from what we know of Voldemort, he does not love; and everything he does is for his own ends to increase his power or improve his security from death. Assuming that he knew of the prophecy, having a child with one of his servants in order to put said prophecy into motion was no act of love or romance. I would suggest, that if Dumbledore knew about the prophecy as Voldemort may have, he would not at all be surprised by Voldemort's actions. After all, it fits Voldemort perfectly to use others for his own ends.

Remember also, that Dumbledore died almost a full year before the Battle of Hogwarts. We don't totally know when Delphini was born, but it's suggested that it was soon before the Battle of Hogwarts. It therefore could very well be that Voldemort did not begin this endeavor until after Dumbledore had died. Obviously, Dumbledore would not have the ability to learn about this if he was already dead.

Finally, Snape was indeed privy to many of the Death Eater's secrets, but not all of them. Voldemort told nobody of his Horcruxes. He would certainly keep the information about his daughter among as few people as possible.

Ultimately, my conclusion is that Dumbledore likely did not know. However, we can't be totally sure of that.

Comment: I would dispute with a notion that Delphini was born _because of_  a new prophecy given by an unknown Seer. There's nothing in the script that would suggest it. 'When spares are spared, when Time is turned, when unseen children murder their fathers: then will the Dark Lord return' This doesn't specify **who** ought to have fulfilled it. Also ' It was Rodolphus Lestrange (...) told be who I was and revealed the prophecy he thought I was destined to fulfill (...)'  So basically, there's no clear-cut indication about Delphi being the "Chosen One" of this prophecy.

Comment: I agree with calypso1993 , there's nothing that suggest that Delphini is supposed to fulfill this prophecy (other than "she wants the prophecy to happend and acts upon this"), let alone conceived in order to fulfill it - otherwise I like this answer :)

Comment: My thought is that Dumbledore would have been dead or Snape would have reported that Bellatrix had a child, or was pregnant. But in the end the play is nonsense... Bellatrix fought in the Battle of Hogwarts and showed no signs of a recent (day? weeks?) birth.

Comment: @calypso1993 I have edited the answer to account for the possibility that Voldemort did *not* know of the prophecy. I think it's doubtful that he didn't; however, I don't have the evidence to back it up.

Comment: @Skooba Yes, it does seem to stretch suspension of disbelief a little far even for HP. However, it's possible it had been a couple of months. Couple that with magic, and it wouldn't be surprising if witches could significantly reduce their recovery time from childbirth (because magic).

Comment: @DBPriGuy, someone on Tumblr who saw the play pointed out that Delphi was planned and _Rodolphus Lestrange_ suggested Bellatrix and Voldemort to have the baby. Because "they wanted the most powerful magical heir possible". Why Voldemort agreed to this is a big mystery to me. Was it the way of _rewarding_ Bellatrix for her fanatical devotion to him?  Ehm...like I was really shocked when I read it. So back to the prophecy timeline, I think it was made (or revealed to Rodolphus) after the death of Voldemort.

Comment: Some people who saw the play after its official premiere said that Delphi was born mere months before the Battle of Hogwarts. Mere, like how many? Two, five, seven? During the Meeting at Malfoy Manor Bella could be at an early stage of pregnancy. Also Voldemort's lines about pleasure and cutting off sick branches of her family's tree take a whole new meaning in the context of the Cursed Child. He didn't want his child to be related to werewolves and Mudbloods (like Ted Tonks).

Comment: "He would certainly keep the information about his daughter among as few people as possible." Hard to keep a huge pregnant belly a secret.

Answer (score 3):

**Did Dumbledore know?**

There's simply no evidence to show that he knew about Voldemort's indiscretion with Bellatrix, not is there any specific indication that Snape was aware either.

**Would he have been surprised?**

I suspect not. He was well aware that Hogwarts had spawned a megalomaniacal monster and he clearly had a very low opinion of Mr Riddle. Given Voldemort's proclivity for surrounding himself with compliant henchpersons, it probably wouldn't shock Dumbledore to find that Voldemort had  *dallied*.